# How i can get text into sleep function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, wait

How i can transfer first line of text in tkinter textbox into wait function in python?

```
input1 = textbox.get("1.0", "2.0")
time.sleep(input1)
```

doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why doesn't it work? How do you know?

Comment: What's `textbox`?

Comment: tkinter doesn't have a "textbox". Are you asking about an `Entry` widget or a `Text` widget? I'm assuming `Text`, but I want to make sure.

Comment: `time.sleep()` will freeze your GUI. Use `root.after(ms,func)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert strings to integers.

`time.sleep(int(input1))`

Answer (score 1):

In case your'e positive its float:

```
input1 = textbox.get("1.0", "2.0")
time.sleep(float(input1))
```